# yql query returning authentication error( bad request:400) error in angular 2 application

Tags: angular2-services, yql, yahoo-finance

I am developing an angular 2 client application and i want to list out the stock details of the various companies using `yql` and yahoo finance api in my application. for this i have added following url in my application but this says authentication error(bad request).  So how to authenticate my application to get the result of `yql` query of finance. I am testing it on the local server `localhost:3000`

```
var query = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20pm.finance%20where%20symbol%3D%22YHOO%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&client_id=consumerKey";          

console.log(this.http.get(query));          

return this.http.get(query).map(res => res.json()) ;
```

and also it is showing this message after querying
"error":{"lang":"en-US","diagnostics":null,"description":"Authentication Error.  The table pm.finance requires a higher security level than is provided, you provided ANY but at least APP is expected"}}

Comment: Same issue here. Have you solved it?

Comment: Yup i have resolved it. I used the following code to fetch the data                                 **/*var query = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("';
 query += sym;
 query += '") &format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=';
 console.log(query);*/**